# can not use views from design library

Tags: android, android-design-library

I have a project and try to run the app but I got errors with the design library that prevent me from running app (contains bottom navigation).

I have tried to download SDK 28 and got SDK Manager told me it is downloaded.
I tried to change it to 27.0.0 and got errors with merging.
I tried migrate to `androidX` but not success also.

Home activity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".feature.home_Activity.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "education.mahmoud.quranyapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
}

 def support_version = '28.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
```

should app run.

Comment: what is the errors?

Answer (score 0):

delete the constraints in your BottomNavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

or replace the parent view linear layout with consraint layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".feature.home_Activity.HomeActivity">

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/homeContainer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I got an error cannot get resolve menu attribute at BottomNavigationView.